# how can i overide django allauth signup success_url

Tags: django, django-allauth

I'm working on a project using allauth and i'm using customer user model and i wan the newly registered user to be redirected to a different page (say profile form page) which will be totally different from the login_redirect_url, I have tried it this way

any idea how i can make this work pls?

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404, redirect, render
from allauth.account.views import  LogoutView 
from django.urls import reverse_lazy
from allauth.account.views import SignupView 
from django.views.generic import TemplateView
from .models import CustomUser


class Signup(SignupView):
    success_url = reverse_lazy('business:company_profile')

    def get_success_url(self):
        return self.success_url
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure there is way to override `SignUp` redirection since when you sign up in the application, you also sign in, which will use the `login_redirect_url`.

If you overrode `login_redirect_url` ([documentation](https://django-allauth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced.html#custom-redirects)) you can update your logic and redirect the user to his profile if some fields are missing/empty?

```py
    def get_login_redirect_url(self, request):
        if not request.user.your_custom_field:
            path = "/accounts/{username}/"
            return path.format(username=request.user.username)
        else
            return "/"
```

You could also implement another logic by adding a bool `is_first_visit` on your `CustomerUser` model (with `default=True`) and set it to `False` after his first visit.

Comment: ohk let me try this out

Answer (score 0):

Is the code that you proposed not working?  What errors does it produce?

On first glance, the view that you've proposed should work.  You would just have to make sure it's being used in "urls.py".

Comment: it's not working, and yes i'm using it in my urls but i still get redirect to the default login_redirect_url i set

Comment: Are you inserting it _before_ the allauth urls? (Django will return the first matching entry in "urls.py".)

Comment: i have it in the app url, and in the app url there's no allauth url, just the url to allauth which i have in the project url

Comment: And in your project-level "urls.py" does the app url get added before the allauth url?

Comment: yea, i've fixed it, i used the next field in the html sign up form